# Can I cross-reference a man page with the relevant source code?

Tags: libc, manpage

The man page for `mmap` on my machine says:

```
#include <sys/mman.h>

void *mmap(void *addr, size_t len, int prot, int flags,
           int fildes, off_t off);
```

Some man page viewers, such as Emacs, convert the include statement into a hyperlink, allowing me to view `/usr/include/sys/mman.h`, which really helpful.

Is there any way I can jump to the source code itself of the function being documented (from the man page)?

Comment: The header file doesn't contain any information about where that source would be located.

Comment: ...and in many cases, you won't even have that source code on your machine in the first place.